# Wants to transfer data between 2 Excel files

Tags: excel

I am having 2 files sit.xls and plan.xls.
In sit.xls

```
Roll No.    Roll No.    Roll No.
10          11          12
5659694     5659724     5659754
5659695     5659725     5659755
```

i want when i click on rollno(5659724) it will automatically transfer or copied to plan.xls
which contain

```
ROW 1       ROW 2
ROLL NO.    ROLL NO.
```

Comment: It's really not clear what exactly you're trying to achieve here. When you click on what - any cell in the 3rd row? - you want what exactly to transfer to the other spreadsheet?

Comment: i want when i click on rollno(eg 5659724 or any roll no) in sit.xls it will automatically transfer to plan.xls which also contain rollno

Answer (score 0):

You can write a VBA code on selection change event in the sit.xls as below. The below code copies the selected cell value in the plan.xls at exactly the same location.

```
  Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
     ' The variable for current cell value
     Dim currentValue As String
     ' The variable for current cell address
     Dim ActiveCellAddress As String
     'Get the value of the current cell from the current sheet Sit.xls
     currentValue = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1
     'Get the address of the current cell from the current sheet Sit.xls
     ActiveCellAddress = ActiveCell.Address
     'Activate the another workbook Plan.xls
     Workbooks("Plan.xls").Activate
     'select the desired range
     Workbooks("Plan.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Range(ActiveCellAddress).Select
     'Copy the value to the desired location
     ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = currentValue
     'Activate the old workbook again
     Workbooks("Sit.xls").Activate
  End Sub
```

Comment: hi Thanks alot but It gives run time error 9 Subscript out if range